# large array searching with numpy

Tags: python, arrays, search, numpy, indices

I have a two arrays of integers

```
a = numpy.array([1109830922873, 2838383, 839839393, ..., 29839933982])
b = numpy.array([2838383, 555555555, 2839474582, ..., 29839933982])
```

where `len(a)` ~ 15,000 and `len(b)` ~ 2 million.

What I want is to find the indices of array b elements which match those in array a. Now, I'm using list comprehension and `numpy.argwhere()` to achieve this:

```
bInds = [ numpy.argwhere(b == c)[0] for c in a ]
```

however, obviously, it is taking a long time to complete this. And array a will become larger too, so this is not a sensible route to take.

Is there a better way to achieve this result, considering the large arrays I'm dealing with here? It currently takes around ~5 minutes to do this. Any speed up is needed!

More info: I want the indices to match the order of array a too. (Thanks Charles)

Comment: Maybe you could create a hashmap mapping elements from `a` to their respective index. Then you just have to look them up in the map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm mistaken, your approach searches the entire array `b` for each element of `a` again and again.

Alternatively, you could create a dictionary mapping the individual elements from `b` to their indices.

```
indices = {}
for i, e in enumerate(b):
    indices[e] = i                      # if elements in b are unique
    indices.setdefault(e, []).append(i) # otherwise, use lists
```

Then you can use this mapping for quickly finding the indices where elements from `a` can be found in `b`.

```
bInds = [ indices[c] for c in a ]
```

Comment: I believe this is doing exactly what I need! I guess this is what you meant by a hashmap? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Yes, a hashmap is more or less another word for a dictionary. In Python, it's called dictionary, or `dict`, or just `{}`, in Java, it's a `Map` or `HashMap`. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Any idea how you'd add the failsafe of an item from a not being found in b?

Comment: I just created a separate set and used: `[ indices[c] if c in b_set else -99 for c in a ]`

Comment: You do not need a separate `set`. Lookup in `dict` is O(1) as well, so you can just do `indices[c] if c in indices else -99`, or use `get` with a default value, i.e. `indices.get(e, -99)`.

Answer (score 0):

This take about a second to run.

```
import numpy

#make some fake data...
a = (numpy.random.random(15000) * 2**16).astype(int)
b = (numpy.random.random(2000000) * 2**16).astype(int)

#find indcies of b that are contained in a.
set_a = set(a)
result = set()
for i,val in enumerate(b):
    if val in set_a:
        result.add(i)

result = numpy.array(list(result))
result.sort()

print result
```

Comment: Thank you! However, I want the indices in the same order as the elements in a. This puts them in the same order as they are in b. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, but you should clarify your questions, as that is not clear.